# How to automatically change the background color of the active split?

Tags: highlight

I use several splits (windows). To quickly identify the splits that has the focus I would like Vim to auromatically adapt the background color of the active split.

Is there a way to do so?

Is it possible to have a different definition of the highlighting group Normal depending if the split (window) is active or not?

[image]

Comment: check `:h wincolor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:h wincolor` for this: https://asciinema.org/a/od7Eh6sVZdw9r65vUrtctZ0PC

Change non-active windows background:

```
hi DimNormal guibg=#203040

augroup ActiveWin | au!
    au WinEnter * setl wincolor=
    au WinLeave * setl wincolor=DimNormal
augroup END
```

[image]

Of course, you can do the opposite -- change active window background:

```
hi NormalActive guibg=#203040

augroup ActiveWin | au!
    au WinEnter * setl wincolor=NormalActive
    au WinLeave * setl wincolor=
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks Maxim! It looks like a charm :-)

Comment: your solution work quite well but I have a problem with some windows where the WinEnter event seems not to be triggered (at least the color remain black). If you open the quickfix window (`:copen`) it works well, if you close it (`:cclose`) it works too but if you reopen it (`:copen`) it remains dimmed (I have the same problem with the NERDTree drawer. Is there another event to solve the problem (I tried WinNew but without success)? Is there something else todo?

Answer (score 1):

Another useful mapping (which I have on `<leader><leader><leader>`, or 3 spaces for me) is to "blink" the current cursor location in an obvious way:

```
" ~/.vim/autoload/bk.vim
function bk#cursor#blink(time) abort
  call bk#cursor#hl_on()
  let time_in_ms = float2nr(a:time * 1000)
  if has('timers')
    let _ = timer_start(time_in_ms, {_ -> bk#cursor#hl_off()})
  else
    exec 'sleep'  time_in_ms  'm'
    call bk#cursor#hl_off()
  endif
endfunction

function bk#cursor#hl_on() abort
  set cursorline cursorcolumn
  redraw
endfunction

function bk#cursor#hl_off() abort
  set nocursorline nocursorcolumn
  redraw
endfunction
```

Along with

```
nnoremap <leader><leader><leader> :call bk#cursor#blink(0.2)<enter>
```

(Adjust timing as needed.)

Comment: @Ben, thanks for the tip :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small variation from the solution of @Maxim that seems more robust:

```
hi DimNormal guibg=#203040

augroup ActiveWin | au!
    au WinEnter,BufEnter * setl wincolor=
    au WinLeave,BufLeave * setl wincolor=DimNormal
augroup END
```